# Algorithm description - is it heapsort or quicksort?

Tags: algorithm

I"m having some trouble telling whether this algorithm is heapsort or quicksort...

Lets say I have an algorithm that I don't have the source code for - it is unstable, performance is good on large datasets, and runs in similar time for ordered and unordered sets.

Without any more information, is it possible to tell whether this algorithm is heapsort or quicksort?

Comment: You don't have the source, but you do have the executable. You can read that, or decompile it and read the decompiler output.

Comment: Is it a question in a test?

Comment: Yes - its an old test question - so purely theoretical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it is mostly* impossible to tell what algorithm was used from the data you have.

---

Both quicksort and heapsort are unstable. Also both handles nicely large inputs (the [constants are not that different](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/90/27369)). So these two things tells us mostly nothing.

The last piece of knowledge is about sorted input. Quicksort is a randomized algorithm, so sorted input is irrelevant here. The running time of heapsort also n logn for [both directions of sort](http://test.scripts.psu.edu/users/d/j/djh300/cmpsc465/notes-4985903869437/solutions-to-some-homework-exercises-as-shared-with-students/2-solutions-clrs-06-07-08.pdf):

> The running time of HEAPSORT on an array of length that is already
> sorted in increasing order is Θ(n lgn), because even though it is
> already sorted, it will be transformed back into a heap and sorted.
>
> The running time of HEAPSORT on an array of length that is sorted in
> decreasing order will be Θ(n lgn). This occurs because even though the
> heap will be built in linear time, every time the element is removed
> and HEAPIFY is called, it could cover the full height of the tree.

---

The only reason how I would try to guess an algorithm is by exploiting the randomness of quicksort. By this I mean that I would run the same dataset many many times, and would see potential fluctuations in time of execution (worse case is `O(n^2)`). If I have not found any significant fluctuations - this is heapsort, otherwise quicksort.

---

May be you will be more lucky if you can analyze the memory it uses. Heapsort requires `O(1)`, where good quicksort needs `O(logn)` additional memory and naive one needs `O(n)`. But you do not have this info at your disposal.

**P.S. Thanks to** Ixanezis and Mooingduck for pointing that quicksort in the real world is not really randomized. I didn't know that [but it is true](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/11469/27369)

Comment: Quicksort is not necessarily randomized. The pivot may be chosen as middle element in a range. Also, it can be a median, which we can find in `O(n)` time, thus providing `O(n log n)` worst-case time for quicksort.

Comment: "Quicksort is a randomized algorithm" I don't think I've ever seen a randomized version of the algorithm in the wild. It's almost always entirely deterministic.  However, along a similar thought, you could try algorithmic complexity attacks to see if you can bomb the quicksort, which would prove it's a quicksort. An easy one is providing a large number of identical values. Most quicksorts become O(n^2) here

Comment: @Ixanezis and Mooingduck, thanks you both for your input. I didn't know that but it looks like you are correct. But I still believe that from just one run of the algorithm and the conditions OP has it is impossible to guess.

Comment: I agree that it's generally impossible to know which algorithm is used. With a median-of-3 or median-of-5 quicksort, it's difficult to run across a data set that will make the implementation exhibit pathological (i.e. O(n^2)) behavior. However, you can *construct* such a case fairly easily. See http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/mdmspe.pdf for details. We implemented that as a test a few years ago ... it brought the .NET sort to its knees. (This was before .NET implemented Introsort).

Comment: Thanks for the detail. It more or less confirms what I thought... but good to know there wasn't anything I was missing from the information provided.

Answer (score 1):

A correctly implemented quicksort runs in linear time on constant arrays (that is, arrays where all the elements are the same). That's because all elements will match the pivot, so after the pivoting step which separates the array into three parts: `(< pivot)(= pivot)(> pivot)` the left and right parts will be empty, and the quicksort will terminate immediately.

Heapsort doesn't have this property: it always runs in O(n log n).

So to distinguish the two, I'd try sorting constant arrays of increasing size, and hope to see a greater than linear slowdown in the heapsort implementation.

This approach can also distinguish heapsort from badly implemented quicksort implementations! If the quicksort separates the array into three parts `(<= pivot)(pivot)(> pivot)`, then the quicksort will take O(n^2) time as the right-hand part will be empty, and the left-hand part will have n-1 items in it. Sorting a 10,000,000 item array will distinguish this bad quicksort from heapsort -- heapsort will take a few seconds on a modern machine, but the badly implemented quicksort will take many minutes.